# From logs, extract specific line after a grep by line number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, sed

I have a file, `debug.log`, from which I want to extract all the lines that immediately precede a specified pattern.

Example:

```
1 blabla
2 blabla
3 HERE THE IMPORTANT THING
4 HERE IT MATCHES MY PATTERN
5 blabla
6 ANOTHER IMPORTANT THING
7 PATTERN
5 blabla
```

Expected result:

```
HERE THE IMPORTANT THING
ANOTHER IMPORTANT THING
```

With the following command, I can extract the line number of the line matching my pattern

```
grep -n PATTERN debug.log |cut -f1 -d:
```

The result is

```
5
8
```

Now I would like to subtract one to each of these numbers, and get the corresponding line with something like:

```
sed -n 4p debug.log
sed -n 7p debug.log
```

This gets my expected result.

Can I automate this, so I don't have to run `sed` by hand like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier and only uses `grep`:

```
grep -B1 PATTERN debug.log | grep -v 'PATTERN\|--'
```

or,

```
grep -B1 PATTERN debug.log | grep -v -e 'PATTERN' -e '--'
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for my purpose. Looks like I had a wrong approach. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a note, that two consecutive matching patterns will upset this: you'll get the line preceding the first pattern, but not the next line - which precedes the second pattern.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's not my case, the line matching patterns are not consecutives. I will try to verify this

Comment: @jcbermu It's true, two consecutive matching patterns won't give you the desired results. Whenever the debug.log content is like the example it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sed alone:

```
sed -n -e '/PATTERN/{x;p;x};h'
```

On each line, if the pattern is matched, then print the hold space.  Regardless, copy the current line into hold space for the next iteration.